# Android App dynamic Shortcut for multi flavour app

Tags: android, shortcut, android-7.1-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

*Could you please help configure the **application package** for **dynamic shortcuts** in Android?*

The application code has **branding** using **product flavouring** via **build.gradle**.

```
productFlavors {
    branda {
        applicationId "com.bb.branda"
        ...
    }
    brandb {
        applicationId "com.bb.brandb"
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...

}
```

For **static shortcuts**, they can be configured in the **shortcuts.xml** file, under the tag "targetPackage".

For eg. **android:targetPackage="com.bb.branda"**

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="contact_us"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/home_contactus_icon"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label.contactus"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/label.contactus"
    >
    <intent
        android:action="contactus"
        android:targetPackage="com.bb.brand"
        android:targetClass="com.bb.launcher.LauncherActivity"
        />
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
```

*For **Dynamic shortcuts**, where could the same be done in the below code snippet?*

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {

        ShortcutManager shortcutManager = ctx.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

        ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(ctx, shortcutId)
                .setShortLabel(sTitle)
                .setLongLabel(sTitle)
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(ctx, resID))
                .setIntent(new Intent(sIntentAction))
                .build();

        shortcutManager.addDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is specify the package for the intent, you can create the intent in the following way:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(sIntentAction);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("your.package.id", YourActivity.class.getName()));
    ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(ctx, shortcutId)
            .setShortLabel(sTitle)
            .setLongLabel(sTitle)
            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(ctx, resID))
            .setIntent(intent)
            .build();
```

Comment: Could you try to improve your answer by explaining how your code would solve the problem?